# My ajax is not working. My page is refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Instead of going through "/settings-change" url it is just refreshing page with data in url

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#change-settings", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let form = $("#change-settings").serialize();
  console.log(form)
  $.ajax({
    url: '/settings-change',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form,
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      window.location.href = "/profile";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="change-settings">
  <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
    <label for="profession" class="control-label">Profession</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="profession" type="text" id="profession" class="form- 
            control" value="$session['user']['profession']" autofocus="" />
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-raised btn-info waves-effect">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Look in the console and network tab.

Comment: Your form has default behavior.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet I made, that when I add jQuery the form does NOT submit. On success, the page should change to `/profile`  - if not, then you need to add error handling too. The default action is a GET of the current page

Comment: Where is this "snippet"? And why are comments disappearing?

Comment: The snippet is the stacksnippet I added to the question that has given the question a [mcve] - and comments disappear when they are deleted by the ppl making them or by mods that remove them when they are unkind or no longer useful